# Differentiating between no input (null String) and Cancel button in JOptionPane.showInputDialog()?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, propertychangelistener

I am using an Input Dialog for user input. The input can be a string value, or simply pressing "OK" to use the default value. With this, there is no way to differentiate between the user specifying the default value (no string input, "OK" button press) and the user canceling ("Cancel" button press). Both return a null String.

It looks like I can register a PropertyChangeListener on the InputDialog, but that requires (apparently) constructing the InputDialog directly, then adding to a JDialog, etc. (all the stuff the JOptionPane does nicely in the background for me now.

Question: Is there some other way to differentiate between "OK" with a null value and "Cancel" without having to build the InputDialog myself and add the PropertyChangeListener?

Comment: `Both return a null String.` - On Windows, I get an empty string when I press OK and a null String when I press "Cancel". It doesn't matter if I set an initial value or not. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr when constructing the minimal SSCCE removing all dependencies (which I mistakenly thought was unnecessary for such a simple question) I found a package I was using is masking the difference between a null and empty Sting. Thus, differentiating is easy (as long as I don't use the offending package). Your test case did lead me to the actual problem, thanks. +1

Comment: `when constructing the minimal SSCCE removing all dependencies (which I mistakenly thought was unnecessary for such a simple question)` - until a problem is solved we don't know what is or isn't relevant, which is why I always suggest creating a SSCCE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `""` for the `initialSelectionValue` parameter to differentiate between OK and Cancel:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Enter a value", "");
```

If the user clicked Cancel, s is null, if the user clicked OK and did not enter a value, it is `""`.

Comment: I get an empty string even if I don't set an initial value and just press OK.

Comment: @camickr I tested this on 1.8.0_45-b15. Did you use the same version of `showInputDialog`?

Comment: I'm saying I used two versions of showInputDialog, one with an initial value and one without. In both cases an empty string was returned. In other words I could not duplicate the problem because I never got "null" when I click Ok. So I am questioning the problem statement of the OP.